# How to build attribute table from raster .tiff in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, geotiff-tiff

I have built a model that goes through a folder of raster files (TIFF), calling each time one file and running a routine.

The problem I am facing is that imported raster files do not have an attribute table. I know how to create it manually for each one, but I would like to incorporate it to ModelBuilder.

When I create manually the attribute table, ArcGIS creates some auxiliary files (XML, OVR and DBF).

Does anyone know if this can be automatized in ModelBuilder? and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a tool for this : [build raster attribute table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m2000000) (management > raster properties). Note that you can right click on it to launch it in batch, without the need of Model builder